# Intellij/Flutter/Supabase edge function - How to suppress warning in TS file

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, supabase, supabase-flutter

I'm using Intellij as the IDE for my Flutter project.

Part of this project includes a 'Supabase' edge function that has one TS file.  The TS file is showing two parsing problems with the TS file

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Deno'.
```

How can I supress these warnings?

```
// Follow this setup guide to integrate the Deno language server with your editor:
// https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/setup_your_environment
// This enables autocomplete, go to definition, etc.

// @ts-ignore
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts';
// @ts-ignore
import { createClient } from "https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2.0.0";

console.log("Delete user account function up and running");

const corsHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-client-info, apikey, content-type',
}

serve(async (req) => {

  // This is needed if you're planning to invoke your function from a browser.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }

  try {
    //Create instance of SupabaseClient
    // @ts-ignore
    const supabaseClient = createClient(
        Deno.env.get("SUPABASE_URL") ?? "",
        Deno.env.get("SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE_KEY") ?? "",
    );

    // Get the authorization header from the request.
    // When you invoke the function via the client library
    // it will automatically pass the authenticated user's JWT.
    const authHeader = req.headers.get("Authorization");

    // Get JWT from auth header
    const jwt = authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");

    // Get the user object
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await supabaseClient.auth.getUser(jwt);

    if (!user) throw new Error("No user found for JWT!");

    //Call deleteUser method and pass user's ID
    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.auth.admin.deleteUser(user.id);

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
      headers: {...corsHeaders,  "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify(error), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      status: 400,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: does adding `// @ts-ignore` above Deno usages help?

Comment: It doesn't have the best reviews, but adding the Deno extensions should hopefully fix it: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14382-deno